# How to append a array of dictionary using object mapper in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, objectmapper

[image][image][image]

After successfully logged in, I am getting this message in my console. Inside the user there is a array list named `UserMedias`. I want to append that `UserMedias` to a empty array list so that I can show the data of `UserMedias` in a table view. I am using just object mapper and Swift 4.

```
var messageList : [UserMedias] = []
```

Please tell me how to append the data of `UserMedias` into a empty array named messageList.

Comment: what is user in second image? please open it and please paste sample json response you are getting from server

Comment: Please paste your json

Comment: uploaded the screenshot. basically user have some fields named 'name' 'username' and a array named 'user_medias'. i want to show that 'user_medias' data to an empty array. please help sir,

Comment: You need to create two objects for the same

Comment: @PPL: sir i have uploaded the screenshot. is it okay?

Comment: Please come on chat

Comment: sir will you please elaborate. i am newcomer in swift..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167733/discussion-between-ppl-and-gorib-developer).

Comment: can you provide me the link of chatroom

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167733/discussion-between-ppl-and-gorib-developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// First store the "user_medias" array in a temporary array

let tempArr = resultDictionary["user_medias"] as! Array <Any>

// Then run this for loop 

for obj in tempArr
{
 let tempDic = obj as! Dictionary < String,Any> 
 emptyArray.append(tempDic)  
 // here emptyArray is the array where you want to append the objects
}
```

Comment: i have create a empty array var messageList : [UserMedias] = [] now i have to run a loop ?

Comment: First you have to fetch the `user_medias` array from the `JSON` result you are getting from _api_ and the you have to run the for loop on using that array where you just stored the `user_medias` array and in that loop you do just what I did, append in the empty array.

Comment: i have fetch the user_medias array from JSON result.please see the screenshot.tell me where i have to run the for loop?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create objects like this,

```
class UserRoot: BaseModel {
    var status: Bool?
    var message: String?
    var userDetails: UserDetails!

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        message <- map["error"]
        userDetails <- map["user"]
        status <- map["success"]
    }
}

class UserDetails: BaseModel {
    var id : Int?
    var userMedias : [UserMedias] = []

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        userMedias <- map["user_medias"]
    }
}

class UserMedia: BaseModel {
    var mediaId : Int?

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        mediaId <- map["mediaId"]
    }
}
```

FYI. Code will be changed as per your requirement. Please do needful changes. Create properties as you need.

Let me know in case of any queries.